# Send SMS messages programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, sms

I am looking for a way to send an SMS using .net applications without using any third party services, like SMS Gateways, etc.

Is there a simple method which I can use to send messages for free at no cost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're looking to avoid spending, you could have C# send an email to a carrier-specific SMS email address. For example Sprint is 5555555555@messaging.sprintpcs.com. Just set up IIS as an SMTP server (or use gmail's). The limitation with this is that you have to know what carrier any given number has.

Comment: Receiving shouldn't be a problem as long as a reply-to address is specified in the message sent; in my experience, most/all phones obey this.

Answer (score 6):

Your SMS will go through a gateway somwhere, whether you talk to that directly or not. Even if you run your own gateway, that has to talk to the  telco systems somehow. So third parties will be involved.

So you're really asking if there are free SMS services - such do exist, but usually with restrictions on use (naturally enough since ultimately SMSs do cost someone money).

How many SMSs are you considering, and what is the purpose of sending them?

Answer (score 5):

There are only 2 ways of doing this.  The first is to go through a normal SMS gateway which will handle the sending for you.  Obviously, this is NOT free.

The second way is to send the message to the service provider yourself.  Unfortunately, this means you need to know who the receiver's cell provider is.  If the receiver ever changes providers, but keeps the phone number due to number portability, they will have to make sure they tell you of the change.

To do this you send an email to something like 9999999999@messaging.sprintpcs.com where the 9's represent the phone number.  here's a [link to an article](http://www.wikihow.com/Text-Message-Online) about this.

Again, this is fraught with potential problems so your best bet is to just buy a block of messages from a gateway and go that route.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextFlow nugget
https://www.nuget.org/packages/TextFlow

Ive used them and it worked well.

Comment: This is a paid service, only 1 message is advertised as free. The question was for a solution without costs.